Change from vertical scroll of the container to horizontal scroll in GSAP Timeline Plugin
I need some help with the GSAP Timeline Plugin.
After reading the documentation, I am trying to practise with this Codepen example applying different things. I don't understand how it is possible to change from vertical to horizontal scrolling of the pages maintaining the horizontal scrolling in the timeline too.
https://codepen.io/michellebarker/pen/QWqdqZV/597a468071d4dce3f7bf0ce80d6cb8d3
Please find here the Javascript code, the HTML and CSS you can find on the link.
import lodashThrottle from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/lodash.throttle@4.1.1";

const scrollContainer = document.querySelector('[data-scroller]')
const sections = gsap.utils.toArray('section')
const track = document.querySelector('[data-draggable]')
const navLinks = gsap.utils.toArray('[data-link]')
const prefersReducedMotion = window.matchMedia('(prefers-reduced-motion: reduce)')

const lastItemWidth = () => navLinks[navLinks.length - 1].offsetWidth

const getUseableHeight = () => document.documentElement.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight

const getDraggableWidth = () => {
    return ((track.offsetWidth * 0.5) - lastItemWidth())
}

const updatePosition = () => {
    const left = track.getBoundingClientRect().left * -1
    const width = getDraggableWidth()
    const useableHeight = getUseableHeight()
    const y = gsap.utils.mapRange(0, width, 0, useableHeight, left)

    st.scroll(y)
}

const tl = gsap.timeline()
    .to(track, {
        x: () => getDraggableWidth() * -1,
        ease: 'none'
    })

const st = ScrollTrigger.create({
    animation: tl,
    scrub: 0,
})

const draggableInstance = Draggable.create(track, {
    type: 'x',
    inertia: true,
    bounds: {
        minX: 0,
        maxX: getDraggableWidth() * -1
    },
    edgeResistance: 1,
    onDragStart: () => st.disable(),
    onDragEnd: () => st.enable(),
    onDrag: updatePosition,
    onThrowUpdate: updatePosition
})

const initSectionAnimation = () => {
    /* Do nothing if user prefers reduced motion */
    if (prefersReducedMotion.matches) return
    
    sections.forEach((section, index) => {
        const heading = section.querySelector('h2')
        const image = section.querySelector('.section__image')
        
        /* Set animation start state */
        gsap.set(heading, {
            opacity: 0,
            y: 50
        })
        gsap.set(image, {
            opacity: 0,
            rotateY: 15
        })

        /* Create the timeline */
        const sectionTl = gsap.timeline({
            scrollTrigger: {
                trigger: section,
                start: () => 'top center',
                end: () => `+=${window.innerHeight}`,
                toggleActions: 'play reverse play reverse',
                // toggleClass: 'is-active',
                // markers: true,
            }
        })
        
        /* Add tweens to the timeline */
        sectionTl.to(image, {
            opacity: 1,
            rotateY: -5,
            duration: 6,
            ease: 'elastic'
        })
        .to(heading, {
            opacity: 1,
            y: 0,
            duration: 2
        }, 0.5)
        
        /* Create a new timeline to add an active class to the nav link for the current section */
        const sectionTl2 = gsap.timeline({
            scrollTrigger: {
                trigger: section,
                start: 'top 20px',
                end: () => `bottom top`,
                toggleActions: 'play none play reverse',
                onToggle: ({ isActive }) => {
                    const sectionLink = navLinks[index]
                    
                    if (isActive) {
                        sectionLink.classList.add('is-active')
                    } else {
                        sectionLink.classList.remove('is-active')
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    })
}

initSectionAnimation()

/* Allow navigation via keyboard */
track.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    const id = e.target.getAttribute('href')
    if (!id || e.key !== 'Tab') return
    
    const section = document.querySelector(id)
    const y = section.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY
    
    st.scroll(y)
})


If you have any example of horizontal scrolling or any help to change this code it would be wonderful.
Thank you for any help
